# PHP > Check if a whole 24 hours have passed with time();

Tags: php, database

Okay, so whenever someone presses a button on my website the time gets stored of when the clicked the button, I store this data using date(); and I do not use any format or something.

Now I want to check if 24 hours have passed from when the clicked the button, if they have they can click it again, if they haven't they can't.

I've always used the Java currentTimeMS but I don't think it's the same, so how would I check if 24 hours have passed from the non-formatted date(); stored in my MySQL Database.

Comment: yeah, that's tricky, got some code that you tried with?

Comment: hint: `60*60*24` = 24 hours

Comment: I only have to code for storing the current time, I haven't figured anything out how to add 24hours to check if those hours have passed.

Comment: @CarlosGonzalez I figured that out ye, in elementary school. What does the date(); function return? the current time in ms?

Comment: Check the documentation.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

Comment: Yeah, I did read that, something with a Unix timestamp, but my English is quite poor and I only understand half of it.

Comment: i think you should use `time()` instead of `date()` (sorry for bad english)

Comment: @CarlosGonzalez I like that hint part :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$timefromdatabase = 1489834968;

$dif = time() - $timefromdatabase;

if($dif > 86400)
{
echo 'more than 24 hours';
}else{
 echo 'less than 24 hours';
}
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, thanks, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: check again, i swap time() and $timefromdatabase

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense.

Comment: It's possible to have to in in one line: time() - $timefromdatabase  > 86400 ? echo 'more than 24 hours' : echo 'less than 24 hours';

Answer (score 3):

// your first date coming from a mysql database (date fields)

```
$dateA = '2013-11-11 23:10:30';
```

// your second date coming from a mysql database (date fields)

```
    $dateB = '2013-11-11 16:27:21'; 

    $timediff = strtotime($dateA) - strtotime($dateB);

if($timediff > 86400){ 
    echo 'more than 24 hours';
}
else
{
 echo 'less than 24 hours';
}
```

Comment: This is what's coming from my Database (as integer), 1489834968

Comment: then yes... subtract this with current timestamp and check if its the result is greater than 86400